# Hibernate one-to-many : On update, changed children are not updated

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have a one-to-many relationship as below -

Parent hbm:-

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ParentClass" table="PARENT_TABLE" schema="schemaname" lazy="false">

        <cache usage="read-write" />

        <id name="id" column="PARENT_ID_ID" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">schemaname.parent_sequence_name</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <version name="versionNumber" column="version_num" type="java.lang.Long" insert="false" />
        <property name="recordStatus" column="RECORD_STATUS" type="java.lang.String" insert="false" />

        <list name="children" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="PARENT_ID" />
            <list-index column="LINE_NUMBER" />
            <one-to-many class="ChildClass" />
        </list>

        &audit;
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Child hbm:-

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ChildClass" table="CHILD_TABLE" schema="schemaname" lazy="false">

        <id name="id" column="CHILD_ID" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="native">
                <param name="sequence">schema.child_sequence_name</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <version name="versionNumber" column="VERSION_NUMBER" type="java.lang.Long" />
        <property name="recordStatus" column="RECORD_STATUS" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="lineNumber" column="LINE_NUMBER" type="java.lang.Long" />
        <many-to-one name="parent" column="PARENT_ID" class="ParentClass" fetch="select" />
    &audit;
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am entering the parent and children in a form and getting into an action class using Struts. The action class does the .saveOrUpdate(parent).

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(parent);
```

When I insert a new parent, it inserts the children fine. After inserting, I shift the control back to the form with the same values. Then, I change some values on a child and submit it again. In this case, I can see (from hibernate logs) that the parent is updated, but the changed child is not updated.

Is there an option in Hibernate to force the changed children to get updated when the parent is updated? If only the changed children cannot be updated, I am ok with all the children getting updated.

If this information is not enough to understand what I am trying to do, please let me know and I will give more information.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:-

I just noticed that Hibernate is throwing this exception on the child records while trying to update :-

```
Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.efleets.services.billing.domain.InvoiceBulk#206]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1761)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2403)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2303)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2603)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at com.efleets.services.common.integration.GenericDAOImpl.flush(GenericDAOImpl.java:115)
```

Thanks. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the parent and children data for the update case?

Comment: The data is set from the form through Struts2 action. There is no real code behind it except for the Struts2 configuration. I have verified that the changed data is in the objects that get passed into the action.

Comment: have you checked what all queries are being fired by hibernate

Comment: Yes, I checked. Hibernate fires all queries for the insert. But, during update, only the query to update the parent is fired.

Answer (score 2):

Your mapping looks correct. Your program probably will work if you drop the `version`clause from the Child.hbm, but that is not a solution because your application wouldn't be correct any more.

The exception which you've got you can easily reproduce with this logic:
Session 1 loads the row.
Session 2 loads the row.
Session 1 modifies any columns of the row and saves it.
Session 2 modifies the row and tries to save it. Now that exception appears.
In a web environment like in your case this generally is not an error. This happens when two users modify the same data at the same time. You have to catch the exception and give a useful message to the second user.

In your case there probably is an error anywhere in your code, not visible in the part which you've posted.
Please check:
Insert and update, are they in the same session or in two different sessions?
If one session, can it happen there is an update to the child by a different session?
if two sessions, do you use the same or different instances of the child(!) object?

What you can do:
- do not use the same instance of any Hibernate database object in two different sessions
- Before modifying, either `evict()` and `load()` or `refresh()` (all methods of `Session`) the parent and perhaps also the children.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation, Johanna. One note: I only have one session (one user). I am getting this error from the same session on subsequent saves. I will try out the other suggestions and let you know.

Comment: Is your application a web application (I guess because you'r using struts)? In a web applications even if there is only one user you can not be sure all requests of this user are exceuted by the same thread, and depending of your Hibernate usage that means it can be different sessions. So if not done yet I recommend to check if it is really the same sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `cascade="all"` instead of `cascade="all-delete-orphan"`

Check

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html

Comment: can you please provide the child hbm and test case to replicate this. i would be very keen to resolve this issue.

Comment: Satosh, thanks. I have added the child hbm to the initial post